# Unable to login from 16.04 GUI but able to login from commandline with su

Tags: login

- Login from GUI with original account is successful
- Login from GUI with second account is **un**successful
- Login from CLI via `su` command is successful

Seeking suggestions to recover the ability to login with the second account at the GUI.  Second account was created with useradd and `/home/account2` does not exist.

Comment: `man useradd`:  _"**useradd** is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,       administrators should usually use **adduser** (8) instead"_. By "login via su" you mean that you are able to use `su` to run commands as the second user? Anyway, try to reset the password of the second user account `sudo passwd account2`, create its home directory and make sure it is owned by it.

Comment: The issue is that `useradd` does not create all the needed folders and add new user to required groups, e.t.c for new user but `adduser` does so use the latter

Comment: In particular, GUI logins require a working home directory (so that the system can write a `.Xauthority` file and so on)

Comment: Excellent responses issue resolved.  @AlexP: promoting your response to an answer will enable me to award credit where credit is due

Comment: @gatorback: Thank you, I have written an answer on the basis of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man useradd`:

> *"**useradd** is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use **adduser** (8) instead"*.

To (re-)enable the functionality of logging in as `account2`:

1. Try to reset the password of the second user account -- `sudo passwd account2`;
2. Create its home directory and make sure it is owned by it